# WCF Soap Services without Soap Action

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have an existing soap client who communicates with a soap service without using the soap action attribute. Now, we have recently substituted this soap service with a C# WCF Service which requires a soap action by default.
When I import the WSDL again, there is no problem. But, I don't want to regenerate the soap client because of backward compatible reasons. This afternoon I found an article with solves my problem: http://spikesoftware.azurewebsites.net/?p=151#comment-396784

The problem now is that my C# client can't invoke most of the soap actions. I can't find out the reason why this is not working anymore. 
The error I received is the following:

Message:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]
>   : Error in deserializing body of request message for operation
>   'GetWorkshops'. OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message
>   body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with the name
>   'GetWorkshops' and namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. Found node type
>   'Element' with name 'GetWorkshops_V2' and namespace
>   'http://tempuri.org/'

The operation contract for these two methods like this:

```
[OperationContract(Action = "GetWorkshops", Name = "GetWorkshops")]
    WorkshopResponse GetWorkshops(<some parameters>)

[OperationContract (Action = "GetWorkshops_V2", Name = "GetWorkshops_V2")]
    WorkshopResponse_V2 GetWorkshopsV2(<some parameters>)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the binding added in web.config?

Comment: My binding is basicHttpBinding

Answer (score 1):

You can try out a couple of things,

1. Please use wsHttpBinding instead of basicHttpBinding
2. Generate a client proxy using svcutil

Comment: I did follow your recommend steps. But, that didn't solve my problem at that moment. After I did this, I dive'd deeper into the real problem what went wrong. After that I discovered the problems was caused by a bug in my custom message dispatcher I wrote. Now it's working OK. Thank you for your help.